# Given an assignment to return specific data using Springboot reactive but the JSON is really complicated

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I am new to Springboot reactive

I was asked to call the following endpoint and return todays weather data only:
https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MLB/33,70/forecast

I believe I need to use something like this...

```
WebClient.create().get()
                .uri("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MLB/33,70/forecast")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(WeatherClass.class)
                .block();
```

Do I need to map out an entire java object to match the JSON at the endpoint? is there an easy way to perhaps just grab the a certain piece of the JSON?

How would I handle something like the @context annotation in the JSON.

Comment: You simply need to find a JSON library you feel comfortable with (there are many)  .Jackson is a common choice. I'd look at json-simple: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/parse-json-java/.  I'm not at all sure what you mean by "@context annotation in the JSON".

Comment: @paulsm4 did you check the response of the API? There are some fields name starting with @ in response body

Comment: If you have specific questions about the return payload from api.weather.gov (which, based on your question, I assume is JSON) ... then please [Edit] your post and show us the payload.  Otherwise, if your question is "How do I parse the payload" (and if the payload is actually JSON), then Jackson is one good choice (it looks like you might already be doing this).  And - as I suggested - JSON.simple might be another good choice for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The `WebClient` in spring boot automatically uses Jackson's `ObjectMapper` to unmarshall json to a java object when the content type of the response is `application/json`. So there is no need to pull in any additional libraries or have to write any specific unmarshalling code, unless you want to use an alternate json-to-java library.

When using Jackson, you don't need to map every field in the json to your java object. You can annotate your java class with `@JsonIgnoreProperties` to inform jackson to ignore any properties that may appear in the json but do not have a matching field in your java object.

An example `WeatherClass` in which you want only the `@context` and `forecastGenerator` unmarshalled would look something like this

```java
    @JsonIgnoreProperties
    public class WeatherClass {
        private final List<Object> context;
        private final WeatherProperties weatherProperties;

        public WeatherClass(@JsonProperty("@context") List<Object> context,
                            @JsonProperty("properties") WeatherProperties weatherProperties) {
            this.context = context;
            this.weatherProperties = weatherProperties;
        }

        private class WeatherProperties {
            private final String forecastGenerator;

            private WeatherProperties(@JsonProperty("forecastGenerator") String forecastGenerator) {
                this.forecastGenerator = forecastGenerator;
            }
        }
    }
```

*Note*
`@context` seems to be an array that can contain multiple types (both objects and strings in your example). I've used `Object` to work around this but obviously isn't the most graceful solution but should be adequate to demonstrate how Jackson works

Alternatively, you can unmarshall the response to a [JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html), which you can then use to traverse the structure of the json without converting it to a java object. For example

```java
        String forecastGenerator = WebClient.create().get()
                .uri("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MLB/33,70/forecast")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(JsonNode.class)
                .block().get("properties").get("forecastGenerator").toString()
```

There are many other annotations provided by Jackson that can used to define how the unmarshaller functions. Too many to cover here. See [Jackson Deserialisation Annotations](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-annotations#jackson-deserialization-annotations)